# How can I modify this function so it also sorts by date?

Tags: javascript

This function sorts columns by clicking on the header of my table, which works fine except for dates.
How can I modify it so that my dates dd/mm/yyyy can be sorted as well. I like to use vanilla JavaScript not jquery if that is possible.
I understand that there has to be some kind of conversion. But this date thing is perplexing.

```js
function sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(n) {
  

  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("MaoDeObraNaoFaturadasPerClientControlPanelPrint");
  switching = true;

  dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {

switching = false;
rows = table.rows;

for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

  shouldSwitch = false;

  x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
  y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

  if (dir == "asc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
 
      shouldSwitch = true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

      shouldSwitch = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (shouldSwitch) {

  rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
  switching = true;

  switchcount ++;
} else {

  if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
    dir = "desc";
    switching = true;
  }
}
  }
  

}
```

```html
<table id='MaoDeObraNaoFaturadasPerClientControlPanelPrint' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(0)'>ID</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(1)'> DATE</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(2)'>FUNCIONARIO</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(3)'>AGE</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(4)'>DESCRICAO</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(5)'>AMOUNT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>106</td>
    <td>25/11/2020</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>100,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>20/09/2020</td>
    <td>Maria</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>200,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>29/12/2020</td>
    <td>Roger</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>50,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>107</td>
    <td>28/01/2020</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>1050,00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives error - you have some weird comment here `first, which contains table headers): * /` and again here `one from current row and one from the next:*/`

Comment: Thank you for that. I removed the erroneous comments. For some reason it's not sorting correctly now. I must have copied something wrong.

Comment: No, it's not sorting by the date column correctly. But it sorts everything else.

Comment: Treat the date Column as separate case for Sorting - Because your code is sorting alphabetically for all the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are sorting alphabetically.

EITHER change the date to

yyyy/mm/dd OR add a special case for the date

I also had to fix the numbers and amounts

the tablesort plugin uses a data attribute to tell the sorter what is what, but this works for your data

```js
function sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(n) {

  let table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("MaoDeObraNaoFaturadasPerClientControlPanelPrint");
  switching = true;

  dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].cells[n].textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
      y = rows[i + 1].cells[n].textContent.trim().toLowerCase();
      const num = /^\d/.test(x)
      const date = num && x.indexOf("/") != -1;
      if (date) {
        let [dd, mm, yyyy] = x.split("/");
        x = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd, 15, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
        [dd, mm, yyyy] = y.split("/");
        y = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd, 15, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
      }
      else if (num) {
         x = +x.replace(",", ".") 
         y = +y.replace(",", ".");
      }
      if (dir == "asc") {
          shouldSwitch = x > y
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
          shouldSwitch = x < y
      }
      if (shouldSwitch) break;
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id='MaoDeObraNaoFaturadasPerClientControlPanelPrint' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(0)'>ID</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(1)'> DATE</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(2)'>FUNCIONARIO</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(3)'>AGE</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(4)'>DESCRICAO</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(5)'>AMOUNT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>96</td>
    <td>25/11/2020</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>100,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>20/09/2020</td>
    <td>Maria</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>200,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>29/12/2020</td>
    <td>Roger</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>50,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>107</td>
    <td>28/01/2020</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>1050,00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, this is super cool. I started to create another separate function to deal with the dates but this is by far better! thank you @mplungain and thanks to everyone else who helped.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet - modified to sort the date column to sort in ascending order :

```js
function CompareDates(d1, d2) {
  var bIsGreater = false;
  var parts1 = d1.split("/");

  var date1 = new Date(parseInt(parts1[2], 10),
    parseInt(parts1[1], 10) - 1,
    parseInt(parts1[0], 10));;

  var parts2 = d2.split("/");
  var date2 = new Date(parseInt(parts2[2], 10),
    parseInt(parts2[1], 10) - 1,
    parseInt(parts2[0], 10));;
  if (date1 > date2) {
    bIsGreater = true;
  }
  return bIsGreater;
}

function sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(n) {


  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("MaoDeObraNaoFaturadasPerClientControlPanelPrint");
  switching = true;

  dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {

    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;

    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

      shouldSwitch = false;

      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (n != 1) {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        } else if (CompareDates(x.innerHTML, y.innerHTML)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (n != 1) {
          if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

            shouldSwitch = true;
            break;
          }
        } else if (!CompareDates(x.innerHTML, y.innerHTML)) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {

      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;

      switchcount++;
    } else {

      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<table id='MaoDeObraNaoFaturadasPerClientControlPanelPrint' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(0)'>ID</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(1)'> DATE</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(2)'>FUNCIONARIO</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(3)'>AGE</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(4)'>DESCRICAO</th>
    <th onclick='sortMaoDeObraPrintItemList(5)'>AMOUNT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>106</td>
    <td>25/11/2020</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>100,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102</td>
    <td>20/09/2020</td>
    <td>Maria</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>white</td>
    <td>200,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101</td>
    <td>29/12/2020</td>
    <td>Roger</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>50,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>107</td>
    <td>28/01/2020</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Green</td>
    <td>1050,00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You forgot the numbers and amounts

Comment: I know... thanks for including them for me. It's going to take me sometime to digest and understand this magnificent bit of code you have created.